# て頂く、てもらう, に. Who does the action?

Tags: grammar

> あなたにとってWAO!!STYLEでの使命は？？
>
> WAO!!STYLEに関わる全ての人を幸せにすること、
>   私を選んでくれた人の期待を超えることです。
>   常に自分の満足ではなく関わる人の幸せを思う人間性をみにつけ、
>   **私に任せたいといってもらえるようにならなければなりません。
>
>   また私に結婚式をまかせていただけるお客様の期待に応え、**
>   その期待を超えていきます。
>
> What is the mission in the WAO!!STYLE?
>
> Making everyone who sticks with the WAO!!STYLE happy,
>   Surpassing the expectations of those who chose me.
>   Acquiring the human nature of not thinking about your satisfaction but the always about happiness of others,
>   Becoming able to be told "I want to rely on you".
>   Moreover, Answering to the expectations of the clients who leave to me their wedding ceremonies and sorpassing those expectations.

I am confused with 貰う and 頂く.
From what I know  貰う=頂く but less polite.
The grammar with て頂く・てもらう is:

> 私が貴方に本を読んでもらう・読んで頂く

The reader is 貴方 and the one who is receiving the favour is 私.

In the sentences above it looks to me that に does not mark the one who does 任せる.
Am I wrong?
Also why is 私に任せたい?
Shouldn't it be 任せて欲しい?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally have the right pattern with 〜て貰う and 〜ていただく, however the に in the two cases doesn't connect directly with these verbs.

```
私に任せたいといってもらえる
```

In this case the person "able to receive" (もらえる) the action is the writer, however the phrase "私に任せたい" simply means "leave it to me". I guess you can think of it as the "私に任せたい" part being separate from the もらえる verb, i.e.

```
(私に任せたい)といってもらえる
```

So 私に任せたい is equivalent "leave it to me", except there is no word for "me" in Japanese so you get 私 ("I").

```
また私に結婚式をまかせていただける
```

Same thing here. The "私に" is referring to the person who it will be left to, entrusted to, not the いただける verb.

This is extremely confusing, but if you read enough of these type of sentences you'll learn to differentiate from context (:

Comment: Shouldn't it be 任せて欲しい if you wanted to say "I want you to leave it to me"?

Comment: Yes, in the context of that simple sentence I think 任せて欲しい is appropriate, however you could also say "任せてもらいたい" which has a very similar meaning.

In the context of the original Japanese text, I feel "(私に)任せたいといってもらえる" is a more appropriate phrase (sounds more polite to me), and  and the phrase "ようにならなければなりません" is use to show the writer wants to reach a state where "任せたいといってもらえる" can happen.

Comment: From what I understand Xといってもらえる="Can receive being said X", so something like "be told X", am I correct? I knew about てもらいたい, but I don't understand if たいといってもらう is another way to say てもらいたい・て欲しい.

Comment: 私に任せたいと言ってもらえる is literally like "can have them say that they want to leave it to me", I think... ("can have them say 'I want to leave it to you'" would be more like 「『あなたに任せたい。』と言ってもらえる」, no?)

Comment: I agree the difference is whether it is quoted (literally) or not, but I think ultimately these two things mean the same thing, right? In English saying "leave it to me" sounds more natural, even though that person would actually be saying "you" when they speak.

Comment: I tought たい could be used only if it is the 1st person  the one who wants something.  
If it's the 2nd-3rd person I should say たがる or add よう、そう、らしい. Is this wrong?

Comment: @Splikie If you're saying they told you (言って), ～たい is perfectly acceptable for other people's wishes.

Comment: ^ Agreed, I think you can say 「3rd personが～～たいと言う・言っている etc.」「3rd person に～～たいと言われる・言ってもらう etc.」, just like you can say 「3rd personが～～たいらしい・たいそうだ・たいようだ」

Comment: I think Splikie may be asking about the   ~たい in my example "任せてもらいたい In this case, the ~たい is actually being used for the first person, since "I" want to "receive" the action of "entrusting" from someone. In other words, I want to be entrusted with something.

Comment: If it were 私に任せて I would understand it, but I don't understand why 私に任せたいと言ってもらう is correct.  
"私に任せる=Leave it to me"; "私に任せたいと言う" does imply someone else is wishing for that?  I cannot understand why is に used with 任せたい. Is it because it's "私に「任せたい」と言う"? Edit. Maybe I got it: "私に「任せたい」と言ってもらう" 任せたい=Quote; 言ってもらう implies someone is telling it to me. に can mark the agent and the receiver in this construction. Is this correct?

Comment: The reason "に" is used here is simply that the pattern for the verb 任せる is
"taskをpersonに任せる". You can see examples here: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/71330/meaning/m0u/まかせる/

Comment: What was confusing me was the fact that I assumed that in てもらう に marked the agent and could not mark a receiver of an action.  Read my edit in the precvious comment, I think I got it. I edited before reading your new comment.

Comment: Yes, as I said in my original answer, the "に" here is not related to "もらう". "に" can mark someone who an action is being done towards （Xに任せる) or it can mark who is doing an action for you　”友達に買って貰う". Anyway, glad you got it (:

Comment: It took me a lot of time but I got it, ahahah. Thanks a lot, this was hard for me.